# Flow of data between process to process and database to database

Tags: uml

In Data Flow Diagram can there be a flow of data between database to database and between one process to another process directly?
I mean I have two database and I want to draw a flow between two of them in the 2nd level, such as they are accessing one another. Also same with process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but in Data Flow Diagram, you can create a data flow between Processes but not between DataStores.

Here's the link to a DFD figure I drew (Since I cannot directly post an image yet)
http://changevision.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/astah_dfd.png

PS: You may want to add a DFD tag instead of uml for this question?